# UNION vs GROUP BY or better solution

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, union

I have a situation where I have some hundred of thousands of rows in database table with, let's say 8 columns, where first two columns indexed (two indexes for each column, and one composite index for both columns), and I have two SQL queries with group by and union like:

```
SELECT MIN(columnOne), columnTwo FROM MyTable
WHERE columnTwo IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY columnTwo
```

and

```
SELECT MIN(columnOne), columnTwo FROM MyTable WHERE columnTwo = 1
UNION
SELECT MIN(columnOne), columnTwo FROM MyTable WHERE columnTwo = 2
UNION
SELECT MIN(columnOne), columnTwo FROM MyTable WHERE columnTwo = 3
```

And it seems that second approach with **unions** works **two(sometimes more) times faster** than first one.

I'm executing this queries in Python so the first one is one liner, and second one I need to generate.

I wonder if second approach is normal, and may be there is third way that I don't know of?

UPDATE:

**columnTwo** and **columnOne** fields in all queries are **not unique**

Example

```
# columnOne columnTwo
1 a         a        
2 b         b        
3 c         b        
4 d         a        
...
```

Explain for query with group by shows this:

```
id  select_type    table        type    possible_keys               key       key_len           ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE         MyTable      index   secondColIndex,bothColIndex bothColIndex    12                 1623713   Using where
```

Explain for query with unions shows this:

```
id  select_type    table        type    possible_keys               key       key_len   ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY        MyTable      ref     secondColIndex,bothColIndex bothColIndex    4   const   217472  Using where
2   UNION          MyTable      ref     secondColIndex,bothColIndex bothColIndex    4   const   185832  Using where
3   UNION          MyTable      ref     secondColIndex,bothColIndex bothColIndex    4   const   175572  Using where
    UNION RESULT   <union1,2,3> ALL                                     Using temporary
```

Indexes in MyTable:

```
Table, Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinality, Sub_part, Packed, Null, Index_type, Comment, Index_comment
MyTable, 0, PRIMARY, 1, Id, A, 1623713, , , , BTREE, , 
MyTable, 1, columnOneIndex, 1, columnOne, A, 1623713, , , , BTREE, , 
MyTable, 1, columnTwoIndex, 1, columnTwo, A, 5737, , , , BTREE, , 
MyTable, 1, bothColumnsIndex, 1, columnTwo, A, 5171, , , , BTREE, , 
MyTable, 1, bothColumnsIndex, 2, columnOne, A, 1623713, , , , BTREE, ,
```

Comment: Good question. Cold/hot data differences?

Comment: Readable, easy to maintain code is important too.

Comment: jarlh, cold/hot data makes almost (some milliseconds) no difference for first approach, but first execution of second approach was slow (almost same as first approach) but further repeating of query execution showed improvement like two times faster than first approach

Comment: But your queries don't do the same - the one with "union" selects 3 records (and it doesn't make sense to use min in there as we select one record by id, I am assuming that `id` is unique), while the first one selects 1 record with minimal width.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, id is not unique, i've updated question

Comment: And you do UNION ALL?

Comment: What does explain say?

Comment: I think even if `id` is not unique, you are still getting 3 rows as a result of "union" query, so you are not actually getting one `min` value as a result, but 3 min values for every group.

Comment: Yes, I need to get 3 rows with min value for each group

Comment: Sorry everyone, I edited my question (it was little confusing), now it's as it is in my code

Comment: jarlh, I added EXPLAIN query to question

Comment: OK, I see it, what's "EXPLAIN SELECT" for the query with "GROUP BY"? Also how you are testing the speed - do you see the speed difference when you run queries directly in the mysql client (to make sure that it's not because of the python code inefficiency)?

Comment: jarlh, I added EXPLAIN for first approach

Comment: @BorisSerebrov, i've updated the question with explain for group by

Comment: I looks like the "group by" query scans 1.6 million records, while sum of "rows" in union query gives around 500K (three times less). How the index for two columns look like? According to [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/minmax-optimization/) you may need it to be `(columnTwo, columnOne)` - the order is important and `columnTwo` should go first.

Comment: @BorisSerebrov, Actually I already have that index with order you mentioned. But also I have two more indexes for each columns, can they affect somehow on each other?

Comment: *"And it seems that second approach with unions works two times faster than first one."* -- and it generates a completely different result set.

Comment: The index `secondColIndex` is completely useless, MySQL can use `bothColIndex` instead. Drop it and the queries that modify the table data will run a little bit faster. It won't improve the speed for the `SELECT` queries, though.

Comment: @axiac, I've updated question with indexes for my table, also added USE INDEX (bothIndex) to query with GROUP BY, but it did not improve speed

Comment: Does the first query run faster if you add `ORDER BY NULL`?

Comment: Also, `col2 IN(1, 2, 3)` behaves like an `OR` clause (`col2 = 1 OR col2 OR col2 = 3`) which, in your case, is forcing MySQL to _scan_ entire index instead of _seeking_ the three values. If by `1, 2, 3` you  actually mean `1, 2, 3` then change the query to `col2 <= 3`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not just increasing value, it's `id`s from another table

Comment: It still looks strange that the index is not used, maybe it's because of the column types or data distribution and it's actually the optimizer limiation. I tried to reproduce your situation on generated data, see [the script](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/mysql-group-by-vs-union/generate.py), but both queries return the result in no time and scanned row count is low (around 600 rows for 800K recrods), also I see "Using index" in "Extra" field of the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: Column one is a datetime and column two is integer

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is due to the limitations of MySQL's optimizer (which may be much improved in the most recent versions).  A `GROUP BY` almost always results in a file sort, limiting the use of indexes.

One alternative is essentially just a simplification of the `UNION` version, but using correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT x.columnTwo,
       (SELECT MIN(columnOne)
        FROM myTable t
        WHERE t.columnTwo = x.columnTwo
       ) as min_columnOne
FROM (SELECT 1 as columnTwo UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as columnTwo UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 as columnTwo
     ) x;
```

This should have essentially the same performance as your version with `UNION`.  The correlated subquery should use the index for the calculation.

Comment: Wow, actually this works faster than just unions, it gives me 0.3 seconds, where for just unions it was something near 1.5 seconds